# How to import .XML code style into Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio on OS X, and want to import `intellij-java-google-style.xml` for my code format.

But I can't find `import` at `Preferences -> Project Settings -> Code Style -> Manage` only `Save as`, `Delete`, `Copy to project`, and `Close` there.

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this?

Comment: @ScottBarta The last version 0.5.8

Answer (score 31):

Copy `intellij-java-google-style.xml` into the directory `$HOME/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14/codestyles/`.

Comment: No longer seems to work. -- at least for .IntelliJIdea13 (AS)

Comment: on 13 and above on osx, `$HOME/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14/codestyles`. more info here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/copying-code-style-settings.html

Comment: You can export/import settings via the File menu: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/exporting-and-importing-settings.html

Comment: Create the `codestyles` directory, if it doesn't exist.

Comment: In windows, copy intellij-java-google-style.xml into "C:\Users\$username\.IdeaIC14\config\codestyles\" , and create the codestyles directory, if it doesn't exist. And then restart Intellij Idea, you can see the codestyle through "Settings -> Editor ->Code Style -> Scheme".

Comment: This no longer works in Android Studio 1.5.1 on OSX - I have posted a new question to learn how to get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860382/how-to-import-xml-code-style-into-android-studio-1-5-1-for-osx

Comment: More recent versions store these settings under `$HOME/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/codestyles`. The `AndroidStudio` directory above may have a version number attached to it, or there may be several of them, e.g. `AndroidStudio1.5`, so if one doesn't work, try another.

Answer (score 14):

In the latest Android Studio (as of this edit, 4.1.1) you can go to `Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scheme -> Settings Icon (Gear) -> Import Scheme...` and import the xml there.

Comment: Awesome. This seems to be the easiest way for Android studio 3.2. Just to clarify, In code style, you'll find Scheme at the top and in the right side of it you'll find a 'settings' kind of icon and when you click on that, you see option to 'Import Scheme'.

Comment: This option is not available.

Comment: I updated the description to be more accurate to current build.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Code Style section may not be available until a project is opened.

Answer (score 13):

I am using Android Studio 1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 and in my case I have an .AndroidStudio1.2 folder in my home directory. In this folder there is a config folder. What I did was the following:

1. I created a new folder called codestyles in the config folder.
2. copied my style xml (in my case named AndroidStyle.xml) into the codestyles folder (.AndroidStudio1.2/config/codestyles/AndroidStyle.xml)
3. Went into File>Settings>Editor>Code Style
4. Chose the AndroidStyle among the listed Schemas.

NOTE: Android Studio does not give you an option to import the xml file. And before you add the file to the codestyles folder there is NO indication that you can change the Schema to your own in any way. But after you have added the file the added schema will be shown among the other schemas.

NOTE 2: In other Operating systems this folder is located elsewhere. For more info on configuration folders see here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Comment: Android Studio 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 save your xml to /home/user/.AndroidStudio2.0/config/codestyles/AndroidStyle.xml

Comment: In AndroidStudio 3.0.1, I had to restart it after step 2) to let him see the new configuration in the Settings.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Android Studio Preview you will need to copy your style xml file to:

> ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreviewX.X/codestyles

where X.X is your Preview version ie. 1.4

Comment: Also note you should create the "codestyles" directory if it doesn't exist. Then you'll need to restart Android Studio, go to Preferences->Editor->Code Styles and choose the correct file.

Comment: Changed to `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.5/codestyles` for AS 1.5.

Answer (score 7):

Also, for those who use Android Studio on windows. Copy your xml file to **`$USER_SPACE$\.AndroidStudio1.X\config\codeStyles`**. If you don't have the codeStyles folder, just create one. And then you will see it in **`Settings->Editor->Code Style->Scheme`**.

Answer (score 5):

Here are steps I used to import my coding style for a project.

1. Place `codingStyle.xml` to .idea folder under your project.
2. In Android Studio select `Project` for coding style scheme, click OK.
3. Place original `codingStyle.xml` to .idea folder again (Android Studio most likely had overwritten with default settings your `codingStyle.xml` when you click OK on step 2)
4. Restart Android Sturdio.

Comment: Please clarify step 2.