# How to import .XML code style into Android Studio 1.5.1 for OSX

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to import official [Google code styles](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml) into Android Studio 1.5.1.

I have placed the file named `intellij-java-google-style.xml` here:

```
/Users/me/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14/codestyles
```

As described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265751/61072) on Stack. However, it does not appear:

[image]

I further attempted the approach [described here](http://metova.com/dev/blog/2014/08/27/how-to-import-the-official-android-code-style-to-android-studiointellij/) and placed the same file in `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta/codestyles`, but that also did not work.

Can anyone suggest the right way to import codestyles in Android Studio 1.5.1? Here is exactly what I am running:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've placed the code style .xml in a path used by IntelliJ IDEA, not Android Studio. The corresponding path for Android Studio is:

```
/Users/me/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.5/codestyles
```

Comment: where is it in windows?